# No handlers could be found for logger "pip.vcs.git"

Tags: git, docker, pip, openedx

On Open edX(github.com/edx/devstack) I ran the following commands after a successful installation:

```
make dev.up
make lms-shell
make upgrade
```

I am stuck with this error message:

```
pip-compile --upgrade -o requirements/edx/base.txt requirements/edx/base.in
No handlers could be found for logger "pip.vcs.git"
```

Any help or debugging tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [old open bug](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/292) in pip-compile.